# Need long term access token for manage videos on Daily Motion APIs

Tags: java

I am consuming daily motion data api in JAVA for uploading videos, because there is no SDK available for JAVA.

But the access token for APIs is expire after very short time and I need to generate it again and again to run the APIs.

Can you please suggest how I can get long term access tokens?

Comment: seems they use OAuth 2.0. Which means you can (in theory, depends on the Oauth 2.0 flow) also request and get a refresh token which will let you request a "refreshed" access token which will again will be valid for a seperate amount of time. Then request another token and so on and on...

Comment: https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/refreshing-access-tokens/

Comment: If you use the client credentials flow (without user credentials) there is no refresh token. The client just authorizes again once the access token isn't valid anymore.